# In Rails: How is existing data affected by data type change?

Tags: datatypes, type-conversion, rails

I'm working on a Rails app and would like to change the datatype for an existing column. It's currently a DateTime type, and I want to change it to a Date type. I found a way to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191405/change-a-column-type-from-date-to-datetime-during-ror-migration), but in this case, the person was not worried about preexisting data.

Right now, I plan to generate a migration...

```
rails g migration change_my_column_in_my_talbe
```

...and make the following change:

```
class ChangeMyColumnInMyTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :my_table, :my_column, :date
  end
end
```

My question is: will the existing data be converted to a Date type, or will I need to create a rake task to convert the values for all of my existing DateTime values?

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33761645/rails-effects-of-changing-the-data-type-of-an-existing-column-with-existing-dat) in which the conversion was from Boolean to String, and it seemed like the change would be automatic for existing data. I just want to be sure before I jump into making this change.

I'm using Rails version 4.2.0 and MySQL version 5.6.27 Homebrew. Any advice on this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to set up a way to test this, and the existing data *did* convert from DateTime to Date types! As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35759526/in-rails-how-is-existing-data-affected-by-data-type-change/35760136#35760136), when doing this with MySQL as the adapter, using `change_table` triggers the following SQL call:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY COLUMN column_name DATE
```

**Two helpful warnings** (courtesy of [@SacWebDeveloper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1004379/sacwebdeveloper))**:**

1. This is an irreversible change, so if anyone else is trying this and may need to reverse, be sure to use the `reversible` command or write out the `up` and `down` changes.
2. When converting from DateTime to Date, be aware that rounding uses fractions of a second. Example: '1999-12-31 23:59:59.499' => '1999-12-31', but '1999-12-31 23:59:59.500' => '2000-01-01'.